Expo New Documentation Deve
I installed my apps apk using the expo development build on my phone. It is working on my android emulator but not so on my android device
How do I fix
Here is the screenshot of what it's showing on my android device
I have tried running the development build again but it is still not working
I just want it to show that it is working

This question has a lot of problems that stop people from being able to help: There is no code, and the symptom is so generic that it could be caused by anything. The screenshot is missing - but even if it was there, screenshots are rarely useful without some kind of code. Please see how to ask a good question for more detailed instructions.

@NikosParaskevopoulos
It is not really about the code.  The way we develop and test App using expo was through the  Expo Go App. since they released expo SDK 51 that method of development has being discontinued according to the documentation. To develop App now you have to use the development build approach which involves running a prebuild known as the development build which creates an APK u can install on your mobile device be it Android or IOS.  https://expo.dev/accounts/kodeguru/projects/seller-app/builds/59bb2fb3-bdac-4625-a181-8f77426b5839.
Here is the Link to the Prebuild install.
